# PySpark(Azure Notebooks) - (Over)writing a csv file in Gen2 Storage container when the dataframe has as a source a csv file

Tags: azure, csv, pyspark, azure-synapse, azure-notebooks

I have an issue with loading a CSV to a dataframe add some rows and overwriting the csv from the source

To make it simple I tried to load the CSV and then overwrite it, this will also not work, and after that, I thought to make it more simple load the CSV and write it to a empty location. Also is not working.

Please help

I made a test script:

```
# Importing the different packages.

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from delta import *



# Importing Spark Packages.
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, hash, array, expr, when, regexp_replace, sha2, concat_ws, concat
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType, IntegerType, TimestampType

df_target = spark.read.options(header='True') \
    .csv ('abfss://sdas@da.dfs.core.windows.net/metadata/Test')


output_path = "abfss://sdas@da.dfs.core.windows.net/metadata/Test/"

df_target = df_target.repartition(1)
df_target.write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").csv(output_path)
```

It gives the following error:

```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [27], line 4
      1 output_path = "abfss://.dfs.core.windows.net/metadata/Test/"
      3 df_target = df_target.repartition(1)
----> 4 df_target.write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").csv(output_path)
      5 #df_target.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(output_path/test.csv)

File /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py:1240, in DataFrameWriter.csv(self, path, mode, compression, sep, quote, escape, header, nullValue, escapeQuotes, quoteAll, dateFormat, timestampFormat, ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace, ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace, charToEscapeQuoteEscaping, encoding, emptyValue, lineSep)
   1221 self.mode(mode)
   1222 self._set_opts(
   1223     compression=compression,
   1224     sep=sep,
   (...)
   1238     lineSep=lineSep,
   1239 )
-> 1240 self._jwrite.csv(path)

File ~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File /opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py:190, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    188 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    189     try:
--> 190         return f(*a, **kw)
    191     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    192         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3902.csv.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:651)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:183)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:901)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:892)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 22) (vm-d5418561 executor 1): java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Operation failed: "The specified path does not exist.", 404, HEAD, https://.dfs.core.windows.net/zmsynapsedlhda/metadata/tmas/Test/test.csv?upn=false&action=getStatus&timeout=90

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate
the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by
recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
       
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.readCurrentFileNotFoundError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:149)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2682)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2618)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2617)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2617)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1190)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2870)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2812)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2801)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Operation failed: "The specified path does not exist.", 404, HEAD, https://.dfs.core.windows.net/zmsynapsedlhda/metadata/tmas/Test/test.csv?upn=false&action=getStatus&timeout=90

It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate
the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by
recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.
       
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.readCurrentFileNotFoundError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:661)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileScanRDD$$anon$$readCurrentFile(FileScanRDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:149)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate
> the cache in Spark by running 'REFRESH TABLE tableName' command in SQL or by
> recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

As per the error message, when you change a data in few rows of the table or dataframe and then quickly query the table or dataframe, this is the anticipated behavior and will face this error.

**To resolve this you can try below solutions:**

- Refresh all cached records connected to the table with below command to fix the problem.

```sql
REFRESH TABLE [db_name.]table_name
```

- Restart your spark pool.

**I tried similar code and it's working fine for me.**

Comment: I'm not using SQL or tables or views and if I restart my spark cluster I also lose my dataframe or am I missing something

Answer (score 0):

Code you ran and code you posted are different. Specifically line 1: `output_path = "abfss://.dfs.core.windows.net/metadata/Test/"`

`posted`

```
output_path = "abfss://sdas@da.dfs.core.windows.net/metadata/tmas/Test/"

df_target = df_target.repartition(1)
df_target.write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").csv(output_path)
```

`from error`

```
Cell In [27], line 4
      1 output_path = "abfss://.dfs.core.windows.net/metadata/Test/"
      3 df_target = df_target.repartition(1)
----> 4 df_target.write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").csv(output_path)
      5 #df_target.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save(output_path/test.csv)
```

Change `"abfss://.dfs.core..."` to `"abfss://output_path = "abfss://sdas@da.dfs.core..."`

---

-Edit-

```py
base_path = 'abfss://sdas@da.dfs.core.windows.net/metadata/'
df_target = spark.read.options(header='True').csv(f'{base_path}/Test').repartition(1)
df_target.show()
print(f'writing to: {base_path}/output')
df_target.write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").csv(f'{base_path}/output')
```

Comment: Thats a mistake from me, but is not the issue. Both locations are the same

Comment: mistake in what? Is the mistake in error message or the code you posted? If error message correct then clearly `abfss://.dfs.core.windows.net/metadata/Test/` is an invalid path and likely the problem.

Comment: @chr1s84 can you run the code I added to bottom of my post and post it's output?

Comment: Ok the code above works, but it does not solve my issue still have the same issue if I do this `base_path = 'abfss://sdas@da.dfs.core.windows.net/metadata/'
df_target = spark.read.options(header='True').csv(f'{base_path}/Output').repartition(1)
df_target.show() print(f'writing to: {base_path}/Intput')
df_target.write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").csv(f'{base_path}/Intput') print(f'writing to: {base_path}/Output')
df_target.write.option("header", True).mode("overwrite").csv(f'{base_path}/Output')` It fails @ the overwriting the Output in the last two lines

Comment: to provide an answer as useful as your comment (which just conveys "it doesn't work"): Although it fails @ the overwriting in the last two lines, the error could be anywhere, not just last two lines.